# Google sheets - search product name for multiple keywords and output an id number

Tags: google-sheets

I have column A with product names, in this example iPhone models from different retailers, so the product titles are written a little bit different.

Here's a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12pLB4uHeQf-VonS6roeU7rz2e2eyM0Mcd0weQ4bHAoM/edit#gid=665632347).

```
              A
    1 | iPhone 13 5G, 128GB, Starlight White
    2 | iPhone 13 blue albastru 128 gb
    3 | iPhone 13 5G, 256GB, (PRODUCT)RED
    4 | IPhone 13 Dual Sim eSim 128GB 5G Negru, Midnight
    5 | iPhone 13 128GB 5G Blue + Cadou Incarcator Reta 20W
```

I have column C which includes 2,3,4 or more keywords for a specific product and column D which includes the products ids:

```
         C                      | D
    1 | 128,negru,midnight      | 789
    2 | 256,red                 | 790
    3 | 128, starlight,white    | 791
    4 | 128,blue                | 792
```

I would need a formula in column B, which searches the A column for keywords present in column C and if it finds all the keywords, outputs the id from column D

E.g

```
          A                                                             | B
    1 | iPhone 13 5G, 128GB, Starlight White                      |791
    2 | iPhone 13 blue albastru 128 gb                            |792
    3 | iPhone 13 5G, 256GB, (PRODUCT)RED                         |790
    4 | IPhone 13 Dual Sim eSim 128GB 5G Negru, Midnight          |789
    5 | iPhone 13 128GB 5G Blue + Cadou Incarcator Reta 20W       |792
```

Can this be done in Google Sheets (or maybe in Excel)?

Comment: You said the condition for what is considered a match is "...if it finds all the keywords." Given your posted sample data, why then does A1 match for "128, starlight, white" when the word "white" does not appear in the A1 string?

Comment: And what is the maximum possible number of comma-separated words that may appear in a Col-C cell?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Google sheets - search product name for multiple keywords and output an id number](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/139833075).

Comment: @ErikTyler you are right, my bad, I will change the example

Comment: I'm still hoping for an answer to my second question above as well as the link to a sample spreadsheet, which you mentioned to "Gabriel Pierce" below was forthcoming.

Comment: @ErikTyler in the example sheet I will link now to the thread the max number of comma-separated keywords is 6, but maybe I would need more. It depends on the product name. My goal is to identify every individual product.

Comment: @doubleunary I did not delete the thread at the Google Community help page. I do not know what happened. Maybe a moderator deleted it. I still can see it if I log in with my user, however, I do not see it if I check it out logged out. Maybe you guys know what's happening. I did not get any message regarding the deletion of my question over there.

Comment: In the Google Sheets forum, a post only gets deleted if the OP deletes it or if it is flagged for abuse. So perhaps a product expert flagged your post, although I would think that to be very unlikely, given that it was not using ugly words or marketing third-party products.

Comment: Three hours ago, you said, "...the example sheet I will link now to the thread..." and such a link is still not included anywhere. Typically, I don't continue to follow a post after the first 24 hours if the poster is not responding or following through with answering questions or supplying information in a timely fashion. (Rule of thumb: the volunteer contributors here shouldn't be checking or responding to a post more than the person who requested the help.) I'm not meaning to be unkind here, just realistic.

Comment: @ErikTyler I have posted the example sheet 5 minutes later in the response for Gabriel Pierce below. Then I thought that is the place to post it, but as I read your comment, maybe I should post it here.  Sorry, I am figuring out now the rules over here :)

Comment: @doubleunary weird, I do not know why it could be flagged, I did not get any notification from Google. Also, the thread appears open for me if I am logged in., there is even an option to delete it.

Comment: @doubleunary should I try to post it again?

Comment: You are getting help here, so posting the same question in another forum is not necessary. I would consider it bad form. Your [Sheets Forum post](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/139833075) continues to show "This page is no longer available."

Comment: @doubleunary thanks, then I hope here I will get a response

Answer (score 0):

[image: An image of a searchable list of products and their keys]

### ID Column

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(ID,IF(IFERROR(FIND(SEARCH, Product),-1) = -1,FALSE,TRUE)))
```

### Product Column

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Product, IF(IFERROR(FIND(SEARCH, Product),-1) = -1,FALSE,TRUE)))
```

### Here is how it works

### Constants Mentioned And Their Locations

- ID - B2:B6 - A list of the IDs
- Product - A2:A6 - A list of Product Names
- Search - E1 - A string of text to filter results by.

This formula says

> I want to filter all of the IDs, based on if I can find the search key in the product name

The `IFERROR` surrounding the formulas is just their to keep things pretty and disabling any errors if it can't return anything.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your answer, but it is not quite what I want. I will create a google sheet where I give more examples asap.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply, I am working on other projects in parallel with this one. 
I thought I would explain what I want with this function: 

I want to scrape the websites of several webshops and create a database where the same products are connected with each other through an ID. Since every webshop has its own naming scheme, I have to identify each individual product through a function - for this I am asking for help here.

Example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12pLB4uHeQf-VonS6roeU7rz2e2eyM0Mcd0weQ4bHAoM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In this example sheet the column A contains the scraped titles from 3 different shops. In column B should the function write the ID and in column C should the function write the general product name.
In column F are the keywords. If the product name contains ALL of the keywords then should the column B, C be populated with the corresponding ID and general product name. The keyword corresponding IDs and general product names are in column G and H.
Can this be done? 
Thanks, Istvan